# JPA Query for Enum String type

Tags: spring, jpa, enums, enumerated-types

I am new to Spring. I have a model named Order which has fields like

id,status,timestamp,customer_id
where status is enum type.
Model looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order_") 
public class Order
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   public long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @NotNull
   public Customer customer;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   @NotNull
   @LastModifiedDate
   @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
   public Date timestamp;

   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @OrderColumn(nullable = false)
   public List<OrderItem> items = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @NotNull
   public Status status = Status.UNCLAIMED;

   public static enum Status
   {
      UNCLAIMED,
      PICKUP, // pickup on the way
      DELIVERY, // delivery on the way
      DELIVERED,
   }


   public static interface Repository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, Long>
   {
       public List<Order> findTop2ByCustomerIdAndStatus(@Param("customer_id") Long customer_id, @Param("status") String status);

   }
}
```

When i run the api end point as 
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/orders/search/findTop2ByCustomerIdAndStatus?customer_id=1&status='UNCLAIMED'

I am getting the response as

```
{
  "timestamp": 1440744058472,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException",
  "message": "Parameter value [('UNCLAIMED')] did not match expected type [app.models.Order$Status (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [('UNCLAIMED')] did not match expected type [app.models.Order$Status (n/a)]",
  "path": "/api/v1/orders/search/findTop2ByCustomerIdAndStatus"
}
```

Kindly advise

Comment: Why do you add quotes aroud the parameter? Use status=UNCLAIMED. Note that there are many layers between an HTTP URL and the JPA query that is executed. What you need to show us is how you define and execute the JPA query.

Comment: @Jasmine Try this url instead `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/orders/search/findTop2ByCustomerIdAndStatus?customer_id=1&status=UNCLAIMED` and check the response.